# Swift - prepareforsegue values not pass into required init

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Values of type Array are supposed to be passed into `forceView2` and `stiffView2` by using `prepareForSegue` in `ViewController1`. However `forceView2` and `stiffView2` are both empty when i println in `ViewController2`.

Can anyone explains why it doesn't work when it is inside the `required init`?

**ViewController1**

```
@IBAction func solve_Pressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Solve", sender: sender)

    }

 override func prepareForSegue ( segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

        if (segue.identifier == "Solve") {
            var svcViewController2 = segue.destinationViewController as springViewController2

            svcViewController2.forceView2 = self.force
            svcViewController2.stiffView2 = self.stiffness
        }
```

**ViewController2**

```
var forceView2 = [Float]()
var stiffView2 = [Float]()
var forceB1 : Float
var forceB2 : Float
var SpringD : [Float]

required init (coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    if(isCheckedGlobal) {
    (forceB1,forceB2,SpringD) = calculateBoundary(&forceView2, stiffView2, springNum) }

else {  println(forceView2)
        println(stiffView2)
        println(springNum)

        SpringD = calculate(forceView2, stiffView2, springNum)
        self.forceB1  = forceView2[0]
        self.forceB2 = 0.0
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your prepareForSegue function? Does your function run?

Comment: yes, my prepareForSegue function run. I am sure there is nothing wrong with my `prepareForSegue` function. My output for `forceView2` and `stiffView2` are both empty, thus I have a run time error in `calculate function`.

Comment: I am sure my `prepareForSegue` works because i tried removing `required init` function and shifted it down to `viewDidLoad`. `forceView2` and `stiffView2` have values from `viewController1`.

Answer (score 2):

The init is done when you instantiate the viewController, at this line : `var svcViewController2 = segue.destinationViewController as springViewController2`. At this time your values are not passed yet.

You should try to `println()` your data in `viewDidLoad` method for example.

**Edit :**

I can't try right now, but you should try something like that :

```
var forceView2 = [Float]()
var stiffView2 = [Float]()
var forceB1 : Float
var forceB2 : Float
var SpringD : [Float]

required init (coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder) 
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if(isCheckedGlobal) {
        (forceB1,forceB2,SpringD) = calculateBoundary(&forceView2, stiffView2, springNum) }

    else {
        println(forceView2)
        println(stiffView2)
        println(springNum)

        SpringD = calculate(forceView2, stiffView2, springNum)
        self.forceB1  = forceView2[0]
        self.forceB2 = 0.0
    }
}
```

Don't forget to check your property (optional, nil, ...) if required.

Comment: ![https://www.dropbox.com/s/m3o6548gxtyp8yi/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-28%20at%2011.39.06%20am.png?dl=0] [Error at `super.init(coder: aDecoder)`]

Comment: You have to initialize each non-optional properties before calling `super.init(coder: aDecoder)`. In your case for : forceB1, forceB2 and SpringD. Either you : 1. Add your properties a default value where you declare them, 2. Set your properties a value (default ?) inside the init (before the call to super), 3. You make your properties optionals (but be sure to setting them a value at some point). Let me know :)

Comment: How do i make my properties `forceB1` , `forceB2` and `springD` optional?

Comment: ? and ! will be what you're looking for optionals. But in order to understand them, you might want to look for Optionals directly in the Apple documentation : http://goo.gl/MlIAa1 . Here is another like that might be useful, from SO : http://goo.gl/n5bw4u . Or even : http://goo.gl/eHWVMz .